# How can we connect aws transcribe from azure functions using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-transcribe

Through AWS lambda, we used to connect with aws transcribe using

```
transcribe = boto3.client('transcribe')
```

Is there any possible way that we can call aws transcribe from azure functions using python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways of doing this. The obvious one is use IAM user
credentials to call `transcribe` on your azure function if they have internet access.

When you use lambda, you provide the permissions to access `transcribe` though IAM **execution role** attached to the lambda. If you do it from outside of AWS, you have to use IAM user  access keys. This means you could create an IAM user with **just enough permissions** to use `transcribe` as needed.

The azure function would use boto3 to interact with AWS `transcribe`. You would have to setup boto3 with the IAM user  access keys.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to include the [Boto 3 SDK](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html) in the deployment package you use. You will not have IAM roles available so you'll be **limited to IAM user** (key and secret).

Have a [requirements.txt](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files) in the root of the [structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python) in this file include boto3 as well as a version by using the below format

```
boto3==1.14.20
```